# Query to List out the records by comparing maximum number and all the records below maximum number

Tags: sql

There are multiple records in table X_PROGRAM_LOCATION.These table contains x_program,location_Id,version.There are multiple x_program and under same name of X_program there are different location_id and various versions.
I want to write a query which can sort out the location_id which are not available in higher version of all x_program but they are in lower versions of x_program.

Note:-I want all the lists of location_Id from lower versions so that i can add those in higher version.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the maximum version for each program/location combination might be sufficient for your purposes:

```
select x_program, location_id, max(version)
from x_program_location pl
group by x_program, location_id
```

You can get the ones not in the highest version by calculating the biggest version and using a having clause:

```
select x_program, location_id, max(version)
from x_program_location pl join
     (select x_program, max(version) as maxv
      from x_program_location
       group by x_program
     ) xp
     on pl.x_program = xp.x_program
group by x_program, location_id
having max(version) < max(maxv)
```